# Is there tools for performance and load testing of REST service?

Tags: rest, load-testing, stress-testing

We have web-application with REST interface. Is there some tools to test it?

Comment: This article explains how to load test a Rest API using OctoPerf: http://octoperf.com/blog/2015/07/28/load-testing-rest-api/

Answer (score 35, accepted):

A RESTful web app/API is just HTTP, so no specialized tools are needed to test performance (as opposed to functional testing, where specialized tools could be helpful). You basically just need to make a lot of HTTP requests and record the results.

I prefer ApacheBench to more complex tools such as JMeter. It's very simple and easily scriptable — just write a shell script. I also find it oriented on HTTP, while tools like JMeter are designed to support simulating human usage patterns.

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/programs/ab.html

Comment: +1 Was aware of JMeter (although I've used Microsoft's old stress tool more) but ApacheBench looks really promising.

Comment: ab looks interesting especially that it has reporting built in. It would be much better if it supported generation of randomized inputs. Does it?

Comment: @pastafarian I don’t think so.

Comment: I think siege is better than ab.

Comment: I've tested ApacheBench and found it to be not as 'concurrent' as it claims to be. I could bring a newly developed webservice down by holding down F5 in Chrome, while ApacheBench hardly put any pressure on it. After a lot of trying and tweaking I discarded it as being useless.

Comment: @GolezTrol thanks for the heads up! Is there another tool that you recommend?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, [SoapUI](http://www.eviware.com/) and [Apache Jakarta JMeter](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/index.html)

Answer (score 3):

REST services should be easy to test with [jmeter](http://jmeter.apache.org).

Comment: How to perform rest load test with JMeter?

Answer (score 2):

As I mentioned in comment better use [siege](http://www.joedog.org/siege-home/) than ab as it has more functionality. But if you need something more complex try [JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/). For JMeter distributed testing you can use  [JMeter in cloud](http://blazemeter.com).